# Error opening sublimetext2

Tags: sublimetext2

When I open sublimetext2 I get the following 2 messages:

> Error trying to parse settings:
>
> No data in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/JSON.sublime-settings`:1:1

> Error trying to parse settings:
>
> Expected value in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/SFTP.sublime-settings`:1:1

The JSON file does not exist, while the SFTP does. How do I create the file, or where can I find it? Saw a similar question on here, but they had the file in their question, I do not.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this an older build or are you using particular packages that require those settings? I don't have either of those files in the directory and the program never complains.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User

```
{
"draw_centered": true, // Centers the column in the window
"draw_indent_guides": false,
"font_size": 12,
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": false,
"word_wrap": true,
"wrap_width": 80  // Sets the # of characters per line }
```

Thanks - if possible then set the values according to it.